# How to Grant Angular Authorization to my REST API Calls for Mobile App

Tags: c#, ionic-framework, api-authorization

I have a C# Azure Web API backend where data is retrieved from a front-end Ionic Mobile App (which is basically an Angular App)

The authorization of users is done via Ionic's cloud service, so they handle the heavy lifting of registering users via FB, Twitter, basic (username/password).

My question is, when I go to call services from my backend API, how can I make sure someone just doesn't read a hardcoded username/password inside of the internal javascript code to access the backend data?

I know it's pretty far fetched, but is there anyway for the API to know the request is actually coming from the app (Android and iOS) and not just from someone trying to insert data and comments from a web browser that is unauthorized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling the API from JavaScript that is available for end users, you can assume that your JavaScript and all the logic/credentials contained within are accessible to all.

There are fairly secure ways around this, and FB/Twitter and their ilk have implemented it (using [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/)). Essentially, on passing credentials to the API, a token is generated, which is then used for subsequent calls to the API instead of the credentials.

You can avoid people randomly firing off 'unauthorized' requests using [nonces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) which are generated when you render the form, and can be used only once to submit the form in question. You can then time-limit the validity of the nonce on the API end. Unfortunately, it's not foolproof, but this will limit the damage of any sort of 'brute-force' attack that you might get.

Again, with any shared 'secret' (that would guarantee the origin of requests), you have to assume that anyone with enough willpower will be able to extract it from apps, thus any method you implement here will be 100% foolproof. Probably the best you can do is have a shared secret generated for each user on each device.

Comment: What a great answer.  I have often thought the same when it comes to this in that anyone with enough want and skill to get it, will...and these little gems you've included are ways to at least make it a little more difficult, but nothing will be 100% secure with these types of applications.

Fortunately, the app isn't holding trade secrets or anything critical, so this should help plenty!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.
Long answer: you can (and must) validate the behaviour of a client but not the client itself.
For example we can take a look on Pokemon Go: after a few hours there were bots able to play, after a couple of weeks Niantic started assuming Machine Learning software engineer and encrypt its API using `unknown6` algorithm for stopping the bots, but after a few days of hard working the bots came again online.
You can use all the secure method of this universe (whit an high expense) but if someone (that have good knowledge of software engineering) want emulate your client at the end I will reach his objective